# SpotBugs NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH_FROM_RETURN_VALUE triggers in strange cases

Tags: java, spotbugs

Have a problem with SpotBugs "Possible null pointer dereference due to return value of called method (NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH_FROM_RETURN_VALUE)".
With Lombok getter:

```
@Generated
public @Nullable Integer getPort() {
    return this.port;
}
```

When i try to get value from object using getPort() and produce it to another method where it can't be null spotbugs shows an error "NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH_FROM_RETURN_VALUE" in strange cases.

Example 1.
Ok here a value possible null.

```
session.connectAndBind(gateway.getHost(), gateway.getPort()); // <--- Error
```

Example 2.
Get same error on unboxing.

```
int port = gateway.getPort() != null ? gateway.getPort() : 0; // <--- Error
session.connectAndBind(gateway.getHost(), port);
```

Example 3.
Still get error on unboxing.

```
int port = 0;
if (gateway.getPort() != null) { // <--- Error
    port = gateway.getPort();
}
session.connectAndBind(gateway.getHost(), port);
```

So why i getting the error?
Find one case when veryfi pass with no errors. Code below.

```
// Pass
Integer port1 = gateway.getPort();
int port = port1 != null ? port1 : 0;
session.connectAndBind(gateway.getHost(), port);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example 1: `connectAndBind` probably takes an `int`, not an `Integer`, so Spotbugs is correct.

Example 2 & 3: Spotbugs doesn't know that both `gateway.getPort()` invocations return the same value. Fix it by using `Integer port = gateway.getPort();`, a null check, then just `port` everywhere else, and the warning should go away. That's basically what you've done in your last example.

Comment: In first example SpotBugs is right because a value from getter can be null.
You right about 2 & 3 examples. Thanks a lot. By the way here's answer from SpotBugs contributor if someone needs it:
"@Nullable Integer getPort() means that it is nullable, here SpotBugs is not smart enough to know that it can't be null, because it is not guaranteed that calling getPort() twice will yield the same return.
Maybe some class is extending it, maybe there's another thread somewhere modifying the value, etc.".
https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/issues/2548